# Importing intents in DialogFlow CX

Tags: dialogflow-cx

I am trying to import a csv formatted list of intents into Google's DialogFlow CX like this:

Intent Display Name,Language,Phrase

r200,en,I wanted to teach you a routine called Check and Circle.

r200,en,I called you over to teach you a strategy called Check and Circle.

r200,en,I want to talk with you about a strategy we can use to answer
questions called Check and Circle.

r200,en,I wanted to teach you a routine called Check and Circle.

But all I get is a never-ending spinning load icon, or an error message:

> Invalid value at 'merge_option'
> (type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.dialogflow.v3alpha1.ImportIntentsRequest.MergeOption)

Is it formatted properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible that you have a matching display name in your intent from an existing agent with your imported agent:

> When importing intents, there may be merge conflicts when the display name for an intent in your existing agent matches that of an imported intent.

Based on this [article](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/intent#export) you have these options on controlling merge behaviours:

- **Replace existing intents**: An imported intent overwrites any same-named intent in your existing agent.
- **Merge with existing intents**: The training phrases of an imported intent are added to the existing intent. If the same training phrases exist, they will not be duplicated.
- **Rename and import as new intents**: The imported intent is renamed by appending "_1" to the display name.
- **Skip the intents**: The existing intent remains unchanged, and the imported intent is ignored.

Comment: unfortunately, no matter how I set it, they still don't load. does the fiel look good to youi?